# pixel code conversion in background

Tags: php, curl, google-ads-api

I have a couple of systems (google adwords, tradedoubler) that I have to track sale conversions for. The problem is, I want to send the conversion notification not as a pixel code where the user sees it, but in the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) background check. I tried to do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);

curl_exec($ch);
```

where $url would be the src attribute for the img tag. Unfortunately, the conversion is not logged. Anyone have any experience with this?

I'm not sure if I've made myself clear so feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent string?

Comment: I thought that the back-end which I am querying might be checking headers or user-agent, but haven't really tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a library that can take care of server-side tracking:

http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

However, this doesn't do conversion tracking. This is because conversions are measured using cookies that are set on the user's machine and passed along when they request the pixel. The server-side doesn't have access to those cookies, because it's in a different domain.

It's possible to hack together some JavaScript code that collects the Adwords cookies and passes those down to your server, but you have to really really want this :)

Alternatively, investigate in using a different set of PayPal API's, such as Direct Payment or Payflow.

Comment: Isn't this for Analytics and not for Adwords? Am I able to track adwords conversions using this library?

Comment: @donkapone that wasn't entirely clear from your question; I don't think this library can do adwords conversion tracking ... but why don't you use PDT and have the conversion pixels on that page? I know, some people hook off before that right? ;)

Comment: That's exactly the problem. If I'll use it, I will not be able to trust the conversion report as a 100% reliable source of information.

Comment: @donkapone I've updated my answer, I think you've basically hit a dead end here :)

Comment: We are accepting a whole lot more payment methods than PayPal, as well. I was thinking, that it should be possible to do it server-side for adwords, since there's no cookies, and just two pixel codes - one of them is shown when the user visits the website through an ad, and another when he/she pays for the product and then google does the checking whether this payment got through with the first pixel code queried. So I just wanted to do the second part server-side.

Comment: @donkapone I'm pretty sure Google uses cookies for the conversion tracking :)